# why nginx always redirect back to index.php after I enter the demo password?

Tags: php, nginx

We plan to change our project from apache to nginx+php-fpm.
However, After I enter the test account and password, it redirct back to index.php.
my college suppose that it probably because I did not setting correctly about php.session in php.fpm.

The following code is the first section of index.php of our project.

```
function IsLogin() {
    if(!isset($_SESSION['sess_userid']))
    {
        $url="index.php";
        echo "<script language='javascript'>";
        echo "top.location='".$url."';";
        echo "</script>";
    }else{
        echo "<script language='javascript'>";
        echo "var  
    account='".$_SESSION['sess_userid']."';";
        echo "</script>";
    }
}
```

Does anyone can give me a clue to debug this problem?